# XGRegressor not fitting data

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.6, xgboost

I would like to run a CV for an XGBoost tree regression on my X_train, y_train data. My target is of integer values from 25 to 40. I tried to run this code on my training dataset

```
# A parameter grid for XGBoost
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
cv_params = {
    'min_child_weight': [1, 3, 5], 
    'gamma': [0.5, 1, 2, 3],  
    'subsample': [i/10.0 for i in range(6,11)],
    'colsample_bytree': [i/10.0 for i in range(6,11)], 
    'max_depth': [3, 5, 7],
    'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.02, 0.1]
    }
# Initialize XGB
xgb_for_gridsearch = XGBRegressor(
    n_estimators = 1000, 
    objective = 'reg:logistic', 
    seed = 7
    ) 
# Initialize GridSearch
xgb_grid = GridSearchCV(
    estimator = xgb_for_gridsearch, 
    param_grid = cv_params,
    scoring = 'explained_variance', 
    cv = 5, 
    n_jobs = -1
    )
xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
xgb_grid.grid_scores_
```

I get an error the fit().
I kinda expected that the CV would just take forever, but not really an error. The error output is a couple of thousand lines long, so I will just put the only part that relates to my code:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

JoblibXGBoostError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-a5c1d517107d> in <module>()
     25     )
     26 
---> 27 xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Does anyone know what this relates to? 
Am I using conflicting parameters?
Would it be better to use xgboost.cv()?
I can also add the whole error code if that would help, should I just add it at the bottom of this question?

UPDATE: added error to a Gist, as suggested [XGRegressor_not_fitting_data](https://gist.github.com/ccasimiro9444/fac1fbcaaecf0d28b09365c63ff6930c#file-xgregressor_not_fitting_data-py), since the error is too long.

Comment: `I can also add the whole error code if that would help, should I just add it at the bottom of this question?` Yes please, it could help

Comment: @TomDLT Cheers, I added the error to a Github repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the full error code, it is easier to help you.
A github repo is fine, yet you may find it easier to use https://gist.github.com/ or https://pastebin.com/

Note that the most helpfull line of the full error is generally the last one, which contains here:

`label must be in [0,1] for logistic regression`

It seems you have used logistic regression (`objective = 'reg:logistic',` in your code), which is a classification loss, and so it requires `y_train` to be an array of either 0 or 1.

You can easily fix it with something like

```py
y_train_bin = (y_train == 1).astype(int)
xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train_bin)
```

Comment: thank you for your tipps. Your fix worked. But since my data is not 0 or 1, I just deleted the `objective` to use the default value and that worked as well.

Comment: With xgboostregressor you don’t need any ‘reg:logistic’ because that’s the default value.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar in the github [documentation](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md) it says `objective [default=reg:linear]`

Comment: @ccasimiro9444 That's what I said..It is default so you don't need mention explicitly.